# adb sideload lineage.zip yields adb: failed to read command: No error

Tags: command-line, adb, lineageos

### TL;DR

Trying to sideload Lineage, I hit a brick wall getting the following error:

```
D:\Setups\XXXXX\Lineage FP3\platform-tools_28.0.2(ADB_1.0.41)>
    adb sideload lineage-17.1-20210104-nightly-FP3-signed.zip
adb: failed to read command: No error
```

The phone displays `Timed out waiting for fuse to be ready.` simultaneously.

### Setting:

I'm trying to install LineageOS on my Fairphone FP3+ using Windows 10. Through workarounds including [first difficulties](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232859/340401) and exploiting the [manufacturer flash all .exe](https://support.fairphone.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048148532), I was able to boot the **[Lineage recovery](https://mirrorbits.lineageos.org/recovery/FP3/20210111/lineage-17.1-20210111-recovery-FP3.img)** and start sideload. `adb devices` returns the following:

```
List of devices attached
A2XXXXXXXXX1    sideload
```

The phone display prints `Now send the package you want to apply to the device with "adb sideload <filename>"...`

### Problem:

I now enter `adb sideload lineage-17.1-20210104-nightly-FP3-signed.zip`, paying attention on having the archive in the same folder as adb (that's the default way, [even if about to change](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/make-adb-fastboot-work-any-folder-windows-0177198/)). The result was

- either `adb: failed to read command: Connection reset by peer` with aparent restart of the recovery boot
- or a `adb: failed to read command: No error` in the cmd, giving me `Timed out waiting for fuse to be ready.` on the phone. I don't trust that error as it doesn't time out by waiting but in an instant after sending the *sideload* command.

I also [double checked](https://krispitech.com/fix-cannot-read-sideload-update/) and cross-switched the cable, USB port, downloads, software versions (Lineage and recovery/ADB), as well as un- and reinstalled all respective drivers.

### More references:

- [Manage the bootloader of your FP3/FP3+](https://support.fairphone.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048646311-Manage-the-bootloader-of-your-FP3-FP3-)
- [Manually install Fairphone OS on FP3/FP3+](https://support.fairphone.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048050332) (from part "**Setting:**", in the process leads to [this link from above for Windows](https://support.fairphone.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048148532))

I also went through these possibly related questions on this site among others:

- [Android adb sideload command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826908/android-adb-sideload-command)
- [adb sideload CM,it shows error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529775/adb-sideload-cm-it-shows-error)

Comment: sideload is broken, adb push file to /cache /data or /tmp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR:

**Try a different host device or new installation** (of the host OS) **instead of giving up!**

---

The solution in this very specific case seems to have been **reinstalling the host OS** (in my case Windows 10). I suspect it to be a driver issue of some sort as the reinstallation of everything used the exact same setups, files etc. *I could guess into some of the multiple DisplayLink-ish software I tried to use for my tablet as secondary USB PC display. (Such as Superbrush, Super Display, VirtualTablet, WiredXDisplay, spacedesk and so on, I tried a few.)*

While this is not a direct answer to the question, I hope, it could help other people stuck like me. The exact same procedure led to the desired, previously blocked resullt.